# post method in asp.net mvc4 goes to other page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, post

I am working with asp.net mvc4.

I have a controller:

```
 public class ExtendedProfileController : ProfileController
    {

        protected override void RegisterSystemRoutes(SanaRouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapSystemPageRoute("Profile", "BalieNr", "BalieNr", "Profile/BalieNr");

            base.RegisterSystemRoutes(routes);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Hallo()
        {
            return View();

        }




        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult BalieNr()
        {

            return View();


        }


        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult BalieNr(IEntityListLoadOptions options, string accountID, ExtendedSalesAgentInfoModel model  /*string accountId, ShopAccountType accountType,Customer.ICustomerListLoadOptions hallo*/)
        {

            var salesAgent = CommerceFramework.ShopAccounts.GetShopAccounts(options);

            foreach (var item in salesAgent)
            {
                if (item.ShopAccountType == ShopAccountType.SalesAgent)
                {
                    if (item.ReferenceId.Contains("DB"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("true");
                    }

                    var customer = CommerceFrameworkBase.SalesPersons.GetSalesPerson(accountID);
                    Console.WriteLine(accountID);

                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("false");
            }

            Console.WriteLine(salesAgent);




            return View();
        }




    }
```

and the method BalieNr is the main method.

So I also have a view, like this:

```
@{

    Layout = LayoutPaths.General;
}

@model Sana.Commerce.Customization.Account.ExtendedSalesAgentInfoModel

<div class="semicolumn">
    @*<div class="text">@Sana.RichText("Login_IntroductionText", makeImagesResponsive: true)</div>*@
    <div class="form-holder">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("BalieNr", "ExtendedProfileController", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Baliecode)
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.Baliecode)
                    </td>

                </tr>


            </table>
            <div class="form-row">


                @*@Sana.SubmitButton("Login", "btn btn-medium btn-login")*@
                <input type="submit" value="Login" />
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    <div>

    </div>
</div>
```

So I define a action method and a controller name.

But if I do a post then it doesnt goes to my post action method in the controller - BalieNr. But it goes to this link:

```
http://localhost:5923/sitemap.xml
```

and also if I put a breakpoint on the post method BalieNr. it doesnt hit that method.

So how to solve it so that it hits the post method BalieNr?

Thank you

if I do this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("BalieNr", "ExtendedProfile", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Baliecode)
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.Baliecode)
                    </td>

                </tr>


            </table>
            <div class="form-row">


                @*@Sana.SubmitButton("Login", "btn btn-medium btn-login")*@
                <input type="submit" value="Login" />
            </div>
        }
```

still doesnt hit the correct method.

I have done it like this:

@{

```
Layout = LayoutPaths.General;
```

}

@model Sana.Commerce.Customization.Account.ExtendedSalesAgentInfoModel

@*@Sana.RichText("Login_IntroductionText", makeImagesResponsive: true)*@
    
      @using (Html.BeginForm(htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form" }))
      {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            
                
                    
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Baliecode)
                    
                    
                

                
                    
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.Baliecode)
                    

                


            
            


                @*@Sana.SubmitButton("Login", "btn btn-medium btn-login")*@
                
            
        }

and now it hits the post method :)

Comment: Try to change 'using (Html.BeginForm("BalieNr", "ExtendedProfileController", FormMethod.Post))' to ' using (Html.BeginForm("BalieNr", "ExtendedProfile", FormMethod.Post))'

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I edit the post

Comment: Mmmh are you sure that the View you are working on is actually linked to your ActionResult? Try to right-click your ActionResult and press 'Go to view' and check if it is linked. If not, right-click on the ActionResult and press 'Add View..'

Comment: in the GET method it comes. BalieNr. The problem is that I can only extend the controllers. But the inde view of BalieNr loads correctly . The problem is with the post method.

Comment: Maybe a routing issue? Can you show your RouteConfig?

Comment: I would create a new Action in the controller `Test` and a `[HttpPost]` version as well for it. Add a view with a basic form on it posting to itself. Do you get a hit on the `HttpPost` action for Test? If not, something outside of this controller is causing the issue. I'd guess Routes.

Comment: since you are using ProfileController custom controller may be it is causing problem

Comment: @Usman. What do you mean with custom controller? Yes. ExtendedProfileController extend from ProfileController. Do you mean that?

Comment: yes it may be possible that maybe something in ProfileController may causing problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
@{

    Layout = LayoutPaths.General;
}

@model Sana.Commerce.Customization.Account.ExtendedSalesAgentInfoModel

<div class="semicolumn">
    @*<div class="text">@Sana.RichText("Login_IntroductionText", makeImagesResponsive: true)</div>*@
    <div class="form-holder">
      @using (Html.BeginForm(htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form" }))
      {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Baliecode)
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.Baliecode)
                    </td>

                </tr>


            </table>
            <div class="form-row">


                @*@Sana.SubmitButton("Login", "btn btn-medium btn-login")*@
                <input type="submit" value="Login" />
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    <div>

    </div>
</div>
```